# Having issues with arranging data in R with dplyr (nycflights data)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the nycflights dataset from the nycflights123 library. I noticed something strange. When I tried to arrange these  to find the worst on-time record of flights by tail number:

```
 #Which plane has the worst on-time record?
    worst_delay %>% 
      group_by(tailnum) %>% 
      select(tailnum,arr_delay,dep_delay) %>% 
      mutate(sum_delay=sum(arr_delay,dep_delay)) %>% 
      arrange(desc(sum_delay))
    View(worst_delay)
```

I got the following:

[image: Console]

However when I run the same command and use View(worst_delay), I get this:

[image: Dataframe]

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi. Please provide a reproducible example. Pictures are not reproducible. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to find out how to do that

Comment: I said its from the nycflights dataset. I'll edit in the code for loading that library if its helpful.

Comment: Which I would need to download and install ... It's good practice to provide as much information as you can if you expect us to provide help ...

Comment: Idk thats just what the book says.

Comment: You haven't assigned your result to any object. You're just viewing the original `worst_delay` dataset. If you want to `View()` your calculations, you could just add a `%>% View()` to the end of the code.

Comment: I just noticed that a moment ago. Edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just forgot to code in the dataset (was "worst delay %/%", shoulda been "worst delay <- flights %/%):

```
library(nycflights123)
data(flights)

worst_delay <- flights %>% 
      group_by(tailnum) %>% 
      select(tailnum,arr_delay,dep_delay) %>% 
      mutate(sum_delay=sum(arr_delay,dep_delay)) %>% 
      arrange(desc(sum_delay))
    View(worst_delay)
```

Comment: I just see a link to this post.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would lead to your desired output as the worst on-time record refers to the plane that had the most number of delays in the data set. So you are dealing with count here.

Comment: What is a better alternative then?

Comment: `flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(tailnum)) %>%
  mutate(on_time = !is.na(arr_time) & (arr_delay <= 0)) %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(on_time = mean(on_time), n = n()) %>%
  filter(min_rank(on_time) == 1)` This is the answer given in this book for the exact same question.

Comment: My book doesn't seem to have an answer section. Tried looking at the end of the chapters and the end of the book. Not sure if I just have a bad copy, but that would be tremendously helpful to have.

Comment: No this is another book which contains solution for R for data science, which is indeed extremely helpful and educative. Use it in conjunction with the book.

Comment: What's the name if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't notice I posted a link to this post instead. Here it is:
https://jrnold.github.io/r4ds-exercise-solutions/transform.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I end up scratching my head so often cuz this stuff is so unintuitive to me. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. These two books are fantastic just take your time with them and don't rush to finish them as soon as possible because they cover a lot of grounds and the exercises have numerous great tips.